# c++ стандартные компараторы для qsort

Tags: c, qsort

Функция qsort принимает последним параметром компаратор.
Подскажите пожалуйста где я могу взять готовый компаратор, чтобы не писать его каждый раз самому? Я знаю что для std::sort есть std::less и прочие, неужели для qsort нет подобного?

Comment: `strcmp`, например, вполне подойдёт в качестве компаратора - если сортировать надо строки.

Comment: qsort — это все же С, С++ — это sort, qsort в нем просто по наследству :)...

Comment: @maestro Как я понимаю, ТС интересуют функции, которые можно передавать в `qsort` *непосредственно*...

Comment: @Harry, действительно, непосредственно не работает. Я думал, что `const char*` может быть неявно приведён к `const void*`.

Comment: @maestro Там не только в этом беда. `qsort` передает указатели на элементы, так что если у вас в массиве лежат `char*`, то в компаратор попадают по сути `char**`, переведенные в `void*`.